# Give an example of a vector, represented as a non-zero vector, that has a similarity of zero to vector c

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

I'm having trouble with the following question, the reason for this is because I am having to find a vector that would result in zero similarity, I have tried getting a perpendicular or orthoganal vector but whenever I used such vectors and measured similarity with cosine of the angle between the vector and vector **c**, I was not getting 0 which I need to be. So how do I get a vector such that customer c would be entirely dissimilar to it?

> Consider the cosine of the angle between vectors as a similarity. One customer of an online book store is represented as 5-dimensional vectors (their review rating) as shown below:
>
> > c = (1, 1, 3, 0, 2)

> > Give an example of another customer, represented as a non-zero vector d, who has a similarity of zero to customer c.

Comment: Why does an orthogonal vector not work? Take for example d = (1,2,1,0,-3). The dot product $c\cdot d=1+2+3+0-6 = 0$, so the similarity sim$(c,d)=\frac{c\cdot d}{\Vert c\Vert \Vert d \Vert} = 0$.

Comment: If you don't mind sharing, what was your method for obtaining this orthogonal vector?

Comment: Let $d = (d_1, d_2, d_3, d_4, d_5)$. Then $c \cdot d = d_1 + d_2 + 3d_3 + 2d_5$. Choose $d_2$ to $d_5$ arbitrarily and set $d_1 = -(d_2 + 3d_3 + 2d_5)$. This is not hard to do. But be aware that this is assuming vector elements can have any value. For databases like the one described, usually the values are not negative. The only way to pick a $d$ with $0$ similarity to $c$ without having negative values would be to make $d_1 = d_2 = d_3 = d_5 = 0$. $d_4$ could still be picked arbitrarily.